# Can you write SQL DELETE code the same as INSERTING a value?

Tags: sql

Randomly decided to dive into some SQL reading.

Can I write a DELETE statement just like a INSERT statement?

example

```
INSERT TABLES table (column1, column2)
VALUES ('cell1', 'cell2);

DELETE FROM  table (column1, column2)
WHERE ('value', 'value');
```

instead of

```
DELETE FROM table
WHERE column1 = 'value', column2 = 'value';
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Neither of those statements is valid.  You *can* write:

```
DELETE FROM table
WHERE column1 = 'value' and column2 = 'value';
```

Some databases allow:

```
DELETE FROM table
    WHERE (column1, column2) = ('value', 'value');
```